# XSLT 2.0: Iterate until element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML structure as follows:

```
<document>
  <text>Here is some text </text>
  <bold>and this part is in bold</bold>
  <text> and this part is not.</text>
  <newline />
  <bold>foo foo foo</bold>
  <newline />
  <newline />
  <text>bar bar bar</text>
</document>
```

I would like to write an XSLT transform which produces output like this:

```
<document>
  <line>Here is some text <b>and this part is in bold</b> and this part is not.</line>
  <line><b>foo foo foo</b></line>
  <blankline>
  <line>bar bar bar</line>
</document>
```

I feel that this is a problem which requires a loop structure over document/* until following-sibling:name() = 'Newline', but I can't quite work out how to structure it.

Here the algorithm which I want to try to write:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text | bold">
  <line>
    <xsl:if test="name() = 'text'>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="name() = 'bold'>
      <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- I want a loop which runs over all following 'text' or 'bold' elements, but stops before the next Newline is reached -->
    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*[self:newline]">
      <xsl:if test="name() = 'text'>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="name() = 'bold'>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- I then want to apply-templates on the next item (the newline) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling" />
  </line>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newline">
  <!-- i need to work out how to ignore single <newline> here but output <blankline> if more than one <newline /> is together. -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, your best bet is to use `xsl:for-each-group` to solve your problem. You need to group your content such that each group ends with a `newline` element. You can then simply process the elements within each group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

        <xsl:template match="document">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="newline">
                    <!-- context node is set to the first element in the group -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="create-line"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- ignore any newline element where the next element is also a newline -->
        <xsl:template match="newline[following-sibling::*[1][self::newline]]"/>

        <!-- output a blankline element for the second of a pair of newlines -->
        <xsl:template match="newline[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::newline]]" mode="create-line">
            <blankline/>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- use a wildcard to match and wrap the groups -->
        <xsl:template match="*" mode="create-line">
            <line><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></line>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="bold">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've used a mode to make the processing of the groups of nodes simpler - you can simply use the built-in templates for your `text` elements and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of the 'group-ending-with' attribute within 'xsl:for-each-group' but that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your general goal can be summarized as:

1. text and bold elements should be transcribed, with the latter annotated with  tags.
2. These transcriptions are grouped together into a single line element. The newline elements in the source separate these groups.
3. Multiple newline elements lead to the output of a blankline element.

If the above is accurate, then you can break up your input into groups, where groups of  elements are separated from groups of other elements. Then process each group separately based on the rules you have put forth:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//node()" group-adjacent="boolean(name(.)='newline')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()='true'">
                <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) gt 1">
                    <blankline/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <line>
                    <!--Process text and bold elements here.-->
                </line>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, it's more tricky but possible:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
  <document>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::newline)][1]|newline/following-sibling::*[not(self::newline)][1]|newline/following-sibling::*[1][self::newline]" mode="first"/>
  </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newline" mode="first">
  <blankline />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="first">
  <line>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[generate-id(following-sibling::newline[1]) = generate-id(current()/following-sibling::newline[1])]" />
  </line>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
  <b>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />     
  </b>
</xsl:template>
```